# Find the maximum of the absolute value of diffrence of two functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to find the maximum of function `difference[f_]`in the frequency range $[{0.1,10^7}]$, where:

```
eq1[x_, f_] := 
4.14 10^19 + (-1.15 10^12 + ((0. + 
      1.9 10^9 I) (1.5 10^8 + (0. + 39012.01 I) f))/
   f) x^2 + (-1.08 10^6 - ((0. + 
      335.92 I) (1.5 10^8 + (0. + 39012.01 I) f))/f) x^4 == 0;

eq2[x_, f_] := 
4.14 10^19 + (-1.15 10^12 + 
   1/f (0. + 1.9 10^9 I) ((0. + 39012.01 I) f + 
      680978.45 ((0. + 0.70 I) Sqrt[-48519.44 + Sqrt[
           2.35 10^9 + 39.47 f^2]] + 
         0.70 Sqrt[
          48519.44 + Sqrt[
           2.35 10^9 + 39.47 f^2]]))) x^2 + (-1.08 10^6 - 
   1/f (0. + 335.92 I) ((0. + 39012.01 I) f + 
      680978.45 ((0. + 0.70 I) Sqrt[-48519.44 + Sqrt[
           2.35 10^9 + 39.47 f^2]] + 
         0.70 Sqrt[
          48519.44 + Sqrt[2.35 10^9 + 39.47 f^2]]))) x^4 == 0;

difference[f_] := 
Abs[1./Re[1./((x /. NSolve[eq1[x, f], x])[[3]])] - 
1./Re[1./((x /. NSolve[eq2[x, f], x])[[3]])]];
```

You can tell by looking at the graph of `difference[f]` that the maximum is around **75**, which is the **correct** value.

```
LogLinearPlot[difference[fr], {fr, 0.1, 10.^7}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.1, 10.^7}, {0., 75}}, GridLines -> {None, {75.}}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Red];
```

[image]

but function `Maximize`gives different result

```
Maximize[{difference[fr], 0.1 <= fr <= 1. 10^7}, fr]
(*{3153.54, {fr -> 1.*10^7}}*)
```

**EDIT:**
I have changed the `difference[f]` function in the following way (based on comments):

```
differenceA[f_] := 
Abs[1./Re[1./((x /. Solve[Rationalize[eq1[x, f], 0], x])[[3]])] - 
1./Re[1./((x /. Solve[Rationalize[eq2[x, f], 0], x])[[3]])]];
differenceB[f_] := 
Abs[1./Re[1./((x /. NSolve[Rationalize[eq1[x, f], 0], x])[[3]])] - 
1./Re[1./((x /. NSolve[Rationalize[eq2[x, f], 0], x])[[3]])]];
```

function `NMaximize` gives

```
NMaximize[{differenceA[fr], 0.1 <= fr <= 1. 10^7}, fr]
(*{0.215309, {fr -> 18957.6}}*)
NMaximize[{differenceB[fr], 0.1 <= fr <= 1. 10^7}, fr]
(*{3153.54, {fr -> 1.*10^7}}*)
```

By plotting these two functions

```
GraphicsRow[{LogLinearPlot[differenceA[fr], {fr, 0.1, 10.^7}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Black}], 
LogLinearPlot[differenceB[fr], {fr, 0.1, 10.^7}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Green]}]}, 
Epilog -> {Inset[legend, Scaled[{0.5, 0.05}]]}]
```

I will get
[image]

Only `differenceB[f]` gives correct plot but its maximization gives wrong value.

Comment: Problems with  numeric precision?. Try: `difference[f_] := 
 Abs[1/Re[1/((x /. Solve[Rationalize[eq1[x, f], 0], x])[[3]])] - 
   1/Re[1/((x /. 
          Solve[Rationalize[eq2[x, f], 0], 
           x])[[3]])]]; NMaximize[{difference[fr], 
  10^2 <= fr <= 10^7}, fr]`?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you for a tip but it still gives a wrong answer.

Comment: @Moonwalk Plot @Mariusz's solution with `PlotRange -> All`. Then change `Solve` to `NSolve` and plot. Clearly there are some numeric precision problems.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi please see the edit